# how to connect gui and main code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanna make a dictionary program that could be run every platform. I coded it and it works basically, the user selects a word with a double click before clicking 'Q' and it gives selected word definition. Then I need a GUI. I made it but I couldn't connect them.

dict.txt's example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9WMJ.png

*Sceptral (a.) Of or pertaining to a scepter; like a scepter. 
Scern (v.t.) To discern; to perceive. 
Schade (n.) Shade; shadow. 
Schah (n.) SeeShah. 
Schediasm (n.) Cursory writing on a loose sheet.*

main code;

```
import pyautogui as pya
import pyperclip  
import time
import keyboard
import re
import sys


liste = list()

def copy_clipboard():
    time.sleep(5)
    pya.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    time.sleep(.01)
    return pyperclip.paste()

def click(key, *args,**kwargs): #
    oldword = pyperclip.paste()
    time.sleep(.01)
    pya.hotkey('ctrl','c')
    newword = pyperclip.paste()
    time.sleep(.01)
    pyperclip.copy(oldword)
    capitalizing = newword.capitalize()
    delete_space = capitalizing.strip()
    word = delete_space
    print(word)

    file = open('dict.txt', 'r') 

    for line in file:  
        if word == line.split(" ")[0]:

            letters = re.sub(word, " ", line)
            liste.append(letters)
            print(liste)
    file.close()


while True:
    try: 
        if keyboard.on_press_key('q',click):
            print('You Pressed a Key!')
            sleep(.01)
            break
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break
```

gui;

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("300x400+1200+200")
window.title("dict")
#window.wm_attributes("-alpha")

button = tk.Button(text = "Yuppi")
button.pack()
sbr = tk.Scrollbar(window)
sbr.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill="y")

text1 = tk.Text(window)
text1.insert(tk.INSERT, liste)#letters or liste has to be here
text1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately connecting a GUI to a backend program requires a overhaul of the backend code. When you make a Tkinter GUI, a lot of the controls that you would usually use in backend, such as "print (…)" becomes more complicatd with tk.Label(window, text=…).place(x=x,y=y). So you will essentially have to incorporate your GUI into your backend code.